# Данные из БД приходят в ASCII

Tags: php, mysql, sql, кодировка

Пытаюсь скриптом достать данные из MySql. Там лежат кириллические строки.

Кодировка таблицы `cp1251_general_ci`, кодировка самой БД та же самая.

В скрипте задано:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

Подключение к бд:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(
    'host',
    'user',
    'pass',
    'db_name'
);

mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET cp1251");
```

Дальше проверяем кодировку того что пришло:

```
mb_detect_encoding($data);
```

Выдает ASCII.

Comment: *Дальше проверяем кодировку того что пришло:* И просмотр "глазом" шестнадцатиричных кодов пришедших байтов это подтверждает?

Comment: Текст с виду похож просто на знаки вопроса

Comment: Шестнадцатиричные коды байтов НЕ МОГУТ быть похожи на знаки вопроса.

Comment: Выглядит примерно так `3f3f3f3f203f3f3f3f3f3f3f203f3f203f3f3f3f3f20`

Comment: Ааа... тогда где-то посередине воткнуто ошибочное преобразование кодировки - оно и заменило нераспознанные в указанной как исходная кодировке символы знаками вопроса. На всякий случай - какая кодировка MySQL-сервера?

Comment: Кодировка сервера: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)